# Connect adb wifi without using tcpip android

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, tcpip

I am using nokia 5.1 plus amd my computer is Dell lattitude E6430 ETG model

I'm using adb wifi and running it through cmd to run my application in mobile without using cable.

I'm doing all these steps

1. adb start-server
2. adb tcpip 5555
3. adb connect :5555

Can I skip step 2? Because I have to connect my mobile through USB cable to do this step and one more thing is I'm using Android studio 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

By default your Android device only listens for ADB connections on USB.

By step 2 `adb tcpip 5555` you define that it should also listen on TCP/IP. Before you execute this command at least once after a device reboot adb will not listen on TCP for adb connections and therefore step 3 `adb connect :5555` will not succeed.

Hence you don't have to execute step 2 every time but at least once after rebooting the device (or after disabling adb wifi mode).

Note: **ADB over Wifi is insecure** as ADB is a plain text protocol. Hence from a security perspective it is like the telnet protocol. You should only enable and use adb over Wifi in a personal secured Wifi, otherwise you open up your device to hackers.